# Export Registrykey via Run Dialog to file with current date in filename

Tags: windows-10, run-dialog

I want to export a registry key via command line into a file with the current date, this works fine using the command line console (cmd.exe):

```
reg export HKEY_USERS\SomeRegKey C:\%date%_RegExport.txt
```

Using the Run Dialog unfortunately the filename becomes `%date%_RegExport.txt` and not `19.03.2020_RegExport.txt`.

Is there a way to make the Run Dialog resolve %date% into an actual date?

Comment: Stick the command in a batch file and run that.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, not exactly what I'm looking for but it would at least be a workaround, feel free to write an answer so I can at least give an upvote